# how to reprompt the user (or loop a prompt), until user terminates programs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I am currently making a simple html page with javascript code where I have to prompt the user with a question to fill in a color-name which changes the background of the page after to the color of the user-input.

If that's done, I'd like to continuously display the prompt on the page so that the user can keep entering color-names until he wishes to exit the page or terminate the program.

It has to be written in the simplest/least amount of codelines as possible, and with the use of `"prompt()" and "background.style.bgcolor".`

Do you know how to do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title> Background Colors</title>
<body onload="changeColor()" ontimeupdate="userInput" load="3sec">
<h1> <b style="text-align: center;">Background Color Changer</b> </h1>
<form name = "myform">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" style="align-items: center; justify-content: center">
    function changeColor()
    {
    var userInput = window.prompt("Enter a background-color:");
    document.bgColor = userInput;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds like a great user experience! BTW: A script tag will not have `style` attributes

Comment: This "_I'd like to continuously display the prompt on the page_" is not possible. You cannot retrieve the input color until the OK button is pressed. The browser closes the prompt automatically at. that time. You'll have to reopen the prompt each time.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt the user for a colour. If the prompt returns a colour, change the background of the document body, and call the function again. If the prompt returns an empty string, or the user clicks cancel, don't call the function.

```js
const body = document.body;

function changeColor() {
  const color = prompt('Enter a color.');
  if (color) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    changeColor();
  }
}

changeColor();
```

```html
<h3>Background Color Changer</h3>
```